# what is the right way to write to a temp file which can be read from other app

Tags: android, file, local-storage, share

It needs to generates a temp file and do share through other possible apps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "share file");
```

But when share with other app the file seems not access able. It is because the file is saved to the app internal dir.

So it needs to saved to a dir belongs to this app (so it will be removed when uninstall, best to be in a temp dir so OS could clean it is needed), and other app could also access it.

Saw getExternalCacheDir(), getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalStorageDirectory(), getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(), not sure which one is right one to use for this case. Anyone has suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The secure way to share files between apps is via a `FileProvider`: see [these Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) for more information.

But they also have a section on [how to make world-writable files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles) via `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But don't want to go FileProvider rout. The problem with Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is it is out side of the app's data path. Is the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION useful for this case?

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about you wanting the file within your own app's directory.

Comment: In that case, write the file to your own app using `getExternalFilesDir` and then use the `FLAG_GRAN_READ_URI_PERMISSION` when sending the `Intent`.  See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file.html#GrantPermissions) for more information.

Comment: played with FLAG_GRAN_READ_URI_PERMISSION seems there is concern that people reported this flag does not work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to keep it inside the app's path. So I am using getExternalStorageDirectory.

```
File dataFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfolder");
    dataFolder.mkdirs();
```